# Ошибка в Dart - "a nullable expression can't be used as condition / an iterator"

Tags: flutter, dart

Я учусь работать на Dart во фрейме Flutter. Вот простейший код, который по идее вопросов не вызывает, но компилятор ругается на на 22 и 24 строчки (ошибки описала в коде через комментарии).

```
void main() {
  var bob = user('bob', 40, true, ['footbal', 'skate']);
  bob.info();

  var alex = user('alex', 23, false, ['basketball']);
  alex.info();
}

class user {
  String? name;
  int? age;
  bool? isHappy;
  List<String>? hobbies;

  user([name, age, isHappy, hobbies]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.isHappy = isHappy;
    this.hobbies = hobbies;
  }
  void info() {
    var happy = isHappy ? 'happy' : 'not happy';//a nullable expression can't be used as condition
    print('user $name is $age yers old. he is $happy. His hobbies:');
    for (var el in hobbies) {//a nullable expression can't be used as an iterator in a for-in loop
      print(el);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При указании в определении типа `?`, переменная может принимать `null`

```
bool? isHappy;
List<String>? hobbies;
```

В данном случае эти два поля могут быть `null`, поэтому их нельзя использовать там, где `null` недопустим.

Например в условии. В этом случае можно добавить проверку, например

```
var happy = isHappy == true ? 'happy' : 'not happy';
```

Так же можно использовать [null-aware оператор](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators), который позволяет указать, какое значение будет использоваться вместо `null`

```
for (var el in hobbies ?? [])
```

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
void info() {
  var happy = isHappy == true ? 'happy' : 'not happy';//a nullable expression can't be used as condition
  print('user $name is $age yers old. he is $happy. His hobbies:');
  for (var el in hobbies ?? []) {//a nullable expression can't be used as an iterator in a for-in loop
    print(el);
  }
}
```

Comment: Также можно добавить проверку через переменную: `bool? _isHappy = isHappy; if(_isHappy != null) var happy = _isHappy ? 'happy' : 'not happy';` Для hobbies будет аналогично. @Grundy добавьте это к ответу пожалуйста

Comment: Я бы еще добавил, не обязательно использовать `nullable` типы. Например в данном примере все поля конструктора можно сделать `required` . Также есть ключевое слово `late`, которое помогает инициализировать `не-nullable` типы потом, но использовать его нужно осторожно.

Comment: Ну и документация по nnbd: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: Спасибо вам большое))))))))